# Ruby problem with returning hash value from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby

MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) in order to reproduce the same problem as mine:

at rspec file place:

```
RSpec.describe 'Nested Array Exercises' do
describe 'find favorite exercise' do
    context 'when Ruby is the favorite' do
    let(:array) do
        [
        { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true },
        { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
        { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
        ]
    end

    it 'returns the hash with the name Ruby' do
        expected_output = { name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }
        expect(find_favorite(array)).to eq(expected_output)
    end
    end

    context 'when there is no favorite' do
    let(:array) do
        [
        { name: 'Python', is_my_favorite?: false },
        { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false },
        { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }
        ]
    end

    it 'returns nil' do
        expected_output = nil
        expect(find_favorite(array)).to eq(expected_output)
    end
    end
end
end
```

at the actual functions file:

```
def find_favorite(array_of_hash_objects)
    array_of_hash_objects.each do | hash |
        hash.each do |key, val|
            if key == :is_my_favorite? && val == true
            hash
            end
        end 
    end
    return nil
end
```

I have created a method called `find_favorite`, which takes an array of hashes (i.e.

```
[{ name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }, { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false }, { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }]
```

What I am asked to do is if any key inside `is_my_favorite` is equal to `true`, I should return the whole hash (i.e. last example would return `{ name: "Ruby", is_my_favorite?: true}`. If no true values show up, I should return `nil` value instead.

I have designed a solution which consists of iterating the first array of hashes (`array_of_hash_objects.each do | hash |`), and then re-iterating the hash to deconstruct it into key and value (`hash.each do |key, val|`). Afterwards, I check `if key == :is_my_favorite? && val == true`, and if so, I try returning `hash`.

It's important to note I created a `return nil` in the beginning of my code.

My main problem is that I am getting the value `nil` when I actually want to receive the hash as a return value.

```
   Failure/Error: expect(find_favorite(array)).to eq(expected_output)
 
   >  expected: {:is_my_favorite?=>true, :name=>"Ruby"}
   >  got: nil
 
   >  (compared using ==)
```

Using ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux] if it helps.

Thank you for the kindness!

Comment: I would recommend that you post a more complete version of your designed solution.  You included bits and pieces but its a little difficult to tell what exactly you're doing without seeing it in its complete form (at least the relevant section).  Please consider editing your post.  I think you'll get a better answer showing you exactly where you're going wrong.  I for one am just having a hard time analyzing it as you have it written.  In the meantime, I posted an alternative solution below.

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: @shimurai No problem.  I see that you edited your question to provide the requested information.  Please see my new answer below.

Comment: Is it possible that there are multiple favorites in the array? How would you handle that, just return the first or a list of all favorites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your edited question, I see that there are a few conditions that weren't met with previous answers.  I also see the main flaw in your code.  Let's start with the flaw:

Your code seems a little overly complicated but it should work just fine if you make this one small change to the 5th line of the following section;

```
def find_favorite(array_of_hash_objects)
    array_of_hash_objects.each do | hash |
        hash.each do |key, val|
            if key == :is_my_favorite? && val == true
            return hash
            end
        end 
    end
    return nil
end
```

Notice that I prepended the line with `return`.  Your problem was that you were iterating through the array just fine but there was no container or method being initiated in order to store or return those results.  Your second to last line was telling the method to return nil no matter what the results of the iteration were.

---

Now for my proposed solution:

I see now that your desired output should either be the single hash containing the `true` value or should be `nil` as opposed to the arrays resulting from the solutions mentioned above.  I would probably do something like this;

```
def find_favorite(input)
  output = nil
  input.each{|h| h[:is_my_favorite?] ? output = h : nil}
  output
end

arr_1 = [{ name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }, { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false }, { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }]
arr_2 = [{ name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: false }, { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false }, { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }]


find_favorite(arr_1)  #=> {:name=>"Ruby", :is_my_favorite?=>true}
find_favorite(arr_2)  #=> nil
```

Within the method definition, a container (`output`) is first defined with a default value of `nil`.  We then iterate through the array and fill `output` with the hash containing a true value.  Otherwise `output` returns the default value.

NOTE:  You could optionally delete `== true ?`  from the block but seeing as how I don't know how the original array is being created, I prefer to leave it in there to expressly communicate exactly what I'm looking for in a very human readable way.  That's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

To follow common Ruby idioms and because `is_my_favorite` is obviously a boolean I would just check that the `is_my_favorite?` key returns a true-ish value.

Note when you need to return an array with the same number of elements that the original array and the new element depend on the elements in the old array then [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is certainly the method you want to use.

```
array= [{ name: 'Ruby', is_my_favorite?: true }, { name: 'JavaScript', is_my_favorite?: false }, { name: 'HTML', is_my_favorite?: false }]

array.map { |elem| elem if elem[:is_my_favorite?] }
#=> [{:name=>"Ruby", :is_my_favorite?=>true}, nil, nil]
```

Comment: This is ALMOST the same solution I posted except that you left off the ```== true``` part.  I’m not sure why some people seem to think this is a better option.  If the goal is to filter out only items that are equal to true then this solution misses the mark in my opinion since even values like ```0```, ```“no”```, and almost any ```object``` will be reported as being ```true```.

Comment: @MichaelB I can only imagine that the people who upvoted my answer and the OP who accepted my answer liked that I didn't just write some code but explained why I did it that way. While it is correct that even values like `0`  are true-ish, the example that the OP posted clearly only works with booleans. Furthermore, a check for `== true` is very uncommon in Ruby and I would argue that it is a code-smell showing that the data structure has not been defined properly.

Comment: You’re right.  I can definitely see why your answer was upvoted.  That part made sense to me.  I was less about that and more about the fact that you chose to use a slightly different but seemingly less definitive approach.  Thanks for the explanation.